# Can't display avatar - PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a private message system and I'm trying to show the avatar for the person who receives the message, but instead of getting the avatar for the receiver, it's trying to get the image for the logged in user.

For the image source, avatars are stored in a folder called `user`. The layout of the folder is user/username/avatar. However, when implemented, the correct user folder is opened, but it searches for the avatar of the logged in user.

Also, one more thing to note. For some reason the avatar of the `sender` (parent message) is shown, but not the receiver.

Here's my PHP.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM users 
    INNER JOIN pm ON users.username = pm.sender 
    WHERE (
        receiver='$logged_in_user' 
        AND parent='x' AND rdelete='0'
    ) 
    OR (
        sender='$logged_in_user' 
        AND sdelete='0' AND parent='x'
    )
    ORDER BY senttime DESC";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$statusnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($statusnumrows > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        //assigning variables
        $avatar = $row["avatar"];
        $sender = $row["sender"];
        $receiver = $row["receiver"];

        if($parent == "x" && $sender == $logged_in_user){
           $profile_pic = '<img src="user/'.$receiver.'/'.$avatar.'" alt="'.$receiver.'">';
        }
     }
}
echo $profile_pic;
```

Comment: You are setting receiver='$logged_in_user' in where clause. It should be receivers id, which in your code is not mentioned anywhere. Actually that query seems really messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this PHP is supposed to yield the receiver's avatar?

Look at the SQL here:

```
INNER JOIN pm ON users.username = pm.sender
```

Try instead:

```
INNER JOIN pm ON users.username = pm.receiver
```

(assuming of course the column is named "receiver" in your schema).

Comment: Thank so much! This fixed it. I'm so silly! Much appreciated!!

Comment: Not so silly ... stuff like this happens.  Sometimes it gets caught before it goes to S.O. though :-)  Thanks for the accepted answer!